# What command can I run to get the oldest pod's name?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to get the name of the oldest pod as part of a script.  It seems like I should be able to run `kubectl get po --no-headers=true`, sort-by AGE, and then just pipe to `head -n1|awk '{print $1}'`, but I can't seem to get sort-by working.  I'm running kubectl 1.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AGE times are in an irregular format (`23m`, `2d`) that’s hard to sort on, but you can ask `kubectl` to write out the time a pod started instead.  The times will come out in the very sortable ISO 8601 format.  This recipe to get the single oldest pod might work for you:

```sh
kubectl get pods \
    --no-headers \
    --output=custom-columns=START:.status.startTime,NAME:.metadata.name \
| sort \
| head -1 \
| awk '{print $2}'
```

The `kubectl` command asks to only print out the start time and name, in that order, for each pod.

Also consider `kubectl get pods -o json`, which will give you a very large very detailed JSON record.  If you have a preferred full-featured scripting language you can pick that apart there, or use a command-line tool like `jq` to try digesting it further.  Any field path can also be inserted into the `custom-columns` output spec.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o=name | head -1
```

I'm not sure what version this started work in, but I'm using it in kubectl 1.12.